# How can I find the GitLab source URL for a private group when importing it to a new GitLab instance?

Tags: gitlab

I am trying to import a private GitLab group from my gitlab.com account to the GitLab instance hosted by my university.

I have ownership rights for the original group and created the necessary personal access token.

However, I doubt that I am using the correct **GitLab source URL**. When I navigate to my group, the URL I see has the following structure:

**https://gitlab.com/GROUPNAME**

I wonder if the actual GitLab source URL should also include the group ID because using the **https://gitlab.com/GROUPNAME** URL is clearly not working.

The error notification I am getting reads:

> No groups found. You don't have the Owner role for any groups in this
> instance.

I cannot make sense of it and would appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon this. But the solution is right in the input. It only wants the **GitLab source URL**, not the group URL. So remove the group name from the URL and it should find all the groups you have access to in the particular GitLab instance.

Comment: But how will it know WHICH of my groups I want to import?